# How do I push a view controller from a custom view action using storyboards/IB?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, storyboard

I have a navigation controller than manages a view with a custom component that does not show up on the storyboards/interface builder.  When I trigger a particular action, I would like to push on the next view controller.  I can do this in code, but I would like to stick to storyboards as much as possible.  Is there a way to establish this link?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `prepareForSegue` in your (root) view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SeguName"]) {
        UINavigationController * navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PlayerDetailsViewController * playerDetailsViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```